# Is the clause "just making sure …" part of previous sentence or part of another incomplete one?

Tags: sentence-construction

I know there are 100 billion - 400 billion stars in the Milky Way Galaxy. So each of the dots in the image below might be a star or a cluster of stars.

[image]

A [video](https://youtu.be/JiE_kNk3ucI) is trying to explain how large the (visible) universe is, starting with the following

> Where we left off in the last video, we were just kind of staring,
> amazed, at this Earth's view of the Milky Way galaxy.

> just making sure
> we understood how enormous and how many stars we were looking at.

> And
> even if each of these dots were a star, this is a huge amount of
> stars.

I re-group the starter into 3 sentences as shown above and I'm confused the second one. Is the part of the first sentence or part of another incomplete one, something like the one below?

> **I'm** just making sure
> we understood how enormous and how many stars we were looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've answered your own question really - it is a shortened way of saying "***I'm** just making sure*".

Omitting one's own pronoun / possessive pronoun like this is quite common, especially in informal, extemporaneous speech.

> -Is that right?
> -Of course it's right.
> -Just checking!

There would be similar constructions where nothing is 'omitted' and it could be considered an additional clause of the previous sentence, for example:

> Let's review what we discussed last time, just to be sure we understood.

In this example, "*just to be sure...*" is a *qualifying clause* that adds the *reason* for the review. The first person is inviting others to do this and stating the reason why they should. The same people being invited by the expression "*let's review*" are the ones that the qualifying clause applies to.

In your example, that is not the case. The previous sentence is a statement about what was previously done. The speaker is giving the reason why *he* is saying this, but he has not used his own pronoun (he only said what "we" did). *He* is the one that is "just making sure", so it is tacit that he ought to have said "*I am* just making sure".